# on selecting checkbox enable submit button - angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

On selecting checkbox i should enable submit button. I am doing it in angular 5 and typescript. Here is my existing code

```
 <mat-checkbox>I agreeTerms & Conditions</mat-checkbox>
<button  mat-button class="NxtBtnWrap"  type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use change event to know if you can enable or not, for example

Ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  disabledAgreement: boolean = true;
  changeCheck(event){
    this.disabledAgreement = !event.checked;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="changeCheck($event)">I agreeTerms & Conditions</mat-checkbox>
<button [disabled]="disabledAgreement" mat-button class="NxtBtnWrap"  type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

For more info [here](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api)

Or you can do it with ngModel:

Ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  checked: boolean = false;
}
```

template:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked">I agreeTerms & Conditions</mat-checkbox>
<button [disabled]="!checked" mat-button class="NxtBtnWrap"  type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Remember you need to import in your module forms module to use ngModel:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and add it in the imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Just wondering: why not bind the checkbox's NgModel to a property like hasUserAcceptedAgreement and then enable/disable the button based on that? The change event works but if you can use model binding and avoid events, it seems like it might be the preferred approach when dealing with forms in Angular.

Comment: How are you adding the model binding ?

Answer (score 2):

In @SergioEscudero answer above, the method

```
changeCheck(event){
    this.disabledAgreement = !event.checked;
  }
```

won't work unless you change it to

```
changeCheck(event){
    this.disabledAgreement = !event.target.checked;
  }
```

Comment: Depending of the Angular Material Design version

Answer (score -1):

It's really rather simple: Make sure your TS defines a FormGroup to work with

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dialogFormGroup = formBuilder.group( {
    confirmAction: [false]
  } );
}
```

Then bind the checkbox to that FormControl, and finally define the disabled property on the button depending on the checkbox control value:

```
<form  [formGroup]="dialogFormGroup">
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="confirmAction">I agreeTerms & Conditions</mat-checkbox>
  <button mat-button class="NxtBtnWrap" type="submit" [disabled]="!dialogFormGroup.controls.confirmAction.value">Submit</button>
</form>
```